# rails convert a string back to date format

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In rails I want to check the following condition:

```
student.bday >= @from_date and student.bday <= @to_date
```

where `@from_date` and `@to_date` are determined as:

```
t = Date.today
@from_date = t.at_beginning_of_week.strftime("%d %b")
@to_date = t.at_end_of_week.strftime("%d %b")
```

But in the database `student.bday` is saved as a string (eg: `17 Aug`). Its not a date field. How can I convert this string (`17 Aug`) into `("%d %b")`format or convert to `17 08` or something like that so that I could check the above condition? Any suggestions?

Comment: Actually strftime() return you the output as a string, I think you should compare a date not strings, and if you save student.bday as string you can convert that into Date object, using strptime(). It will return you the Date object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Date.parse("17 Aug")
# Sun, 17 Aug 2014
```

You may want to bring everything to the same year for the comparison to be effective, just to make sure.

```
bday = Date.parse("#{student.bday} #{Date.today.strftime('%Y')}")
```

But default behaviour is to add current year, so this is just redundant...

Better still, provide a parse model, for parsing to be most accurate

```
bday = Date.strptime("#{student.bday} #{Date.today.strftime('%Y')}",'%d %b %Y')
# %d: day of month, %b: Short month, %Y: Year
```

Comment: I am getting an error at the parse statement `b = Date.parse("#{student.bday} #{Date.today.strftime('%Y')}",'%d %b %Y')` as `invalid date`

Comment: is `student` initialized?

Comment: The parse statement is used inside the for loop - `for student in @students` `b = Date.parse("#{student.bday} #{Date.today.strftime('%Y')}",'%d %b %Y')` `end`

Comment: instead of `for student in @students` do `@students.each do |student|`

Comment: The answer you suggested solved my problem. Thank you :) There was a record without a `bday` value. So it was trying to parse a nil value and that caused the error.

Comment: You can check against nil case, if you put at the end of the line `unless student.bday.nil?` for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your student.bday into the required format as:

```
Date.parse(student.bday).strftime("%d %m")
```

This will give the output as "17 08"